# Rails route to many controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My controllers are:

```
A::B::C::SomeController  
A::B::C::SomeOtherController  
A::B::C::ThatController
```

All of them have action :show. My goal is to make a beautiful one line route like:

```
scope :beautiful do
  scope :route_to do
    get ':controller' => 'a/b/c/:controller#show'
  end
end
```

to see them in the address bar like:

```
beautiful/route_to/some  
beautiful/route_to/some_other  
beautiful/route_to/that
```

Is it possible in rails (4.2)?

upd. for now i've stopped at cyclic route render, but still i'm not satisfied.

```
scope :beautiful do
  scope :route_to do
    A::B::C::BaseController.descendants.each do |my_controller|
      scope controller: my_controller, module: 'a/b/c' do
        get my_controller, action: :show
        post my_controller, action: :update
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: @Tilo this article contains route rules for simple websites. mine one is webapp

Comment: the answer is no - it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

what about something like this:

```
namespace :a do
  namespace :b do
    namespace :c do
      resource :something, only: [:show] # => will take controller A::B::C::SomethingController (file must be located at: app/controllers/a/b/c/something_controller.rb)
      resource :something_other, only: [:show]
      ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: this is not an option. since i have N controllers it would take N rows to build the route. but the question was to make 1-line-route.